# NoReverseMatch at /products/

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to route between urls. Product is a class that:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, 
blank=True)
    summery     = models.TextField(blank=True)
    feature     = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product-detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

and its view is like:

```
def product_list_view(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()  # list of objects

    context = {
        "object_list": queryset
    }
    return render(request, "products/product_list.html", context)
```

html:

```
{% block content %}

{% for instance in object_list %}
<p>{{ instance.id }} - <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}">{{ 
instance.title }}</a></p>
{% endfor  %}

{% endblock %}
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', product_list_view, name='list'),
    path('create/', render_initial_data, name='product_create'),
    path('<int:my_id>/', dynamic_lookup_view, name='product-detail'),
    path('<int:my_id>/delete/', product_delete_view, 
name='product_delete'),

]
```

this should work but when I runserver and try to see list of products it raise this error: `NoReverseMatch at /products/` while I use this method in instances of object list.
what is wrong with the `#reverse` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product-detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

you have given `id` as the url parameter but in `url` config you have used `my_id` so change anyone and use the same name

```
path('<int:my_id>/', dynamic_lookup_view, name='product-detail'),
```